# How to store session in mobile app after login request

Tags: java, android

I am facing conceptual issue on how to store session in mobile app after sending login request to API. Basically what I have done so far I created web server using Node.js and I handle sessions using express-session. What I want to to is to create mobile client for Android using Java to let the user login to their accounts and then perform specific activity which will send POST request to my API. My question is after sending login POST request from mobile app, how should I handle the session and is someone could recommend tool which would help I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session from web development is called as **[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)** in Android.

It allow you to save and retrieve data in the form of key,value pair.

In order to use shared preferences, you have to call a method getSharedPreferences() that returns a SharedPreference instance pointing to the file that contains the values of preferences.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```